# Is it possible to forward function calls with matching template type for a std::any-like container?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, stdbind, stdany

I haven't found a way to achieve what I want but I'm not knowledgeable enough to know if its impossible. Help would be appreciated.

The main data data container in our software behaves a bit like a std::variant or std::any: It has a base class `BaseContainer` that provides a type enum. The derived instance `DataContainer` holds the actual data in a typed tensor member variable. So a simplified example boils down to something like this:

```cpp
BaseContainer* vContainer = new DataContainer<float>({1000000});
if (vContainer->getType() == DataTypes::FLOAT)
    const Tensor<float>& vTensor = dynamic_cast<DataContainer<float>>(vContainer)->getData();
```

We have many methods that process data based on the underlying templated type and dimensions:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void processData(const tensor<T>& aTensor, ...other arguments...);
```

The problem is, for every method like `processData()` that we want to call with a `BaseContainer`, we need to write a binding method that unravels the possible types to call the typed version of `processData()`:

```cpp
void processData(BaseContainer* aContainer) {
    switch (vContainer->getType()) {
        case DataTypes::INT8:
            return processData(dynamic_cast<DataContainer<int8_t>>(vContainer)->getData());
        case DataTypes::UINT8:
            return processData(dynamic_cast<DataContainer<uint8_t>>(vContainer)->getData());
        case DataTypes::INT16:
            return processData(dynamic_cast<DataContainer<int16_t>>(vContainer)->getData());
        case DataTypes::UINT16:
            return processData(dynamic_cast<DataContainer<uint16_t>>(vContainer)->getData());
...
        default:
            throw(std::runtime_error("Type not supported"));
    }
}
```

My question is: Is it possible to make a single "adapter" method (in any released version of c++) that can take a function (like `processData()`), a BaseContainer and potentially a list of arguments, and invoke the correct template binding of this function with the arguments?

I failed to bind a template function dynamically because I was not able to pass the name without the template type. Yet the template type would need to be dynamic based on the BaseContainer. But maybe there are other means to achieve what I want to do? I'm very curious about any solution, mostly also to extend my understanding, as long as the complexity of the solution is below writing hundreds of adapter methods.

If nothing else, would it be possible to generate the "adapter" methods using preprocessor macros?

Comment: `std::variant` has `std::visit`. Either get rid of the home-grown solution and use `std::variant`, or write your own version of `std::visit`.

Comment: If you are doing `dynamic_cast`, you have virtual methods. Perhaps a visitor pattern could be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass overloads by name, but you can pass functor with overloaded `operator()` as generic lambda have.

So

```
template <typename F>
auto dispatch(BaseContainer& vContainer, F f) {
    switch (vContainer.getType()) {
        case DataTypes::INT8:
            return f(dynamic_cast<DataContainer<int8_t>&>(vContainer).getData());
        case DataTypes::UINT8:
            return f(dynamic_cast<DataContainer<uint8_t>&>(vContainer).getData());
        case DataTypes::INT16:
            return f(dynamic_cast<DataContainer<int16_t>&>(vContainer).getData());
        case DataTypes::UINT16:
            return f(dynamic_cast<DataContainer<uint16_t>&>(vContainer).getData());
...
        default:
            throw (std::runtime_error("Type not supported"));
    }
}
```

with usage

```
dispatch(vContainer, [](auto* data){ return processData(data); });
```

Comment: There are several good answers now, most based on the visitor pattern. But I chose this as the accepted answer because it gives very good flexibility and easy integration into existing code, with respect to functions that have several arguments.
The lambda can default-bind most arguments. Only the actual containers `BaseContainer` need to be pulled through `dispatch()`. This keeps the code short and readable. It was also easy to add more variants of `dispatch()` that take two or more containers, based on recursion: No need to specify the dot product of possible types in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to write a small wrapper class for each `processData`-like function, you could do something like this:

```
// One like this for each function.
struct ProcessDataWrapper {
  template <typename... Args>
  static auto run(Args&&... args) {
    return processData(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

template <typename Wrapper>
auto ProcessGeneric(BaseContainer* aContainer) {
    switch (vContainer->getType()) {
        case DataTypes::INT8:
            return Wrapper::run(dynamic_cast<DataContainer<int8_t>>(vContainer)->getData());
    // ...
}

// Called as
ProcessGeneric<ProcessDataWrapper>(myContainer);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but as the comments say, it might be worth conidering std::visit.

Here's a solution requiring c++17 that only requires two lines for each function template you want to wrap. You could use a simple macro to simplify the wrpping further.

The core idea is to have a `cast` function that maps from a `DataType` enum to the correspondng `DataContainer` and then to leverage c++17 fold expressions to wrap the switch statement in your code.

Here's the `cast` function, so we have exactly one place to map from `DataType` to the actiual `DataContainer`:

```
template<DataType t>
constexpr inline decltype(auto) cast(BaseContainer& c) {
    if constexpr(t == INT) return static_cast<DataContainer<int>&>(c);
    else if constexpr(t == FLOAT) return static_cast<DataContainer<float>&>(c);
    ... map all other enum values ...
}
```

This is rather a convenience helper to make the following code a bit more readable. The next code block uses the c++17 fold expression to dispatch the function based on the type of the container.

```
template<DataType... types>
auto dispatcher_impl = [](auto f) {
    // NB: capture by value here only for sake of readbility. 
    return [=](BaseContainer& c, auto... args) {
        ([&]{ if(c.GetDataType() == types ) {  std::invoke(f, cast<types>(c), args...); return true; } return false; }() || ...);
    };
};

auto data_type_dispatcher = [](auto f) {
    return dispatcher_impl<INT, FLOAT, ... other types here ...>(f);
};
```

The core idea is to wrap the function into a lambda that checks the DataContainer's DataType and calls the function only if it matches. The Fold expression over the `||` operator is used to unpack the `DataTypes`.

Usage example:

```
template<typename T>
void processData(DataContainer<T>& c, int arg) {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, int>) std::cout << "int";
    else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, float>) std::cout << "float";
    std::cout << ", arg: " << arg << '\n';
}
```

// This needs to be done for each function:
auto pd = data_type_dispatcher([](auto& c, int arg) { processData(c, arg); });

```
int main() {

    DataContainer<float> f;
    DataContainer<int> i;
    pd(f, 2); // prints float, 2
    pd(i, 4); // prints int, 4
}
```

Full example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zrezbb).

In order to throw an exception if the type is not supported, simply add a lambda that throws at the end of the fold expression:

```
    ([&]{ if(c.GetDataType() == types ) {  std::invoke(f, cast<types>(c), args...); return true; } return false; }() || ...  || []() -> bool{ throw (std::runtime_error("Type not supported")); }());
                                                                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```